# custom navigation menu napili by profile in a community salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I want to know if it's possible to limit the visible Menu Items in a Community with Profiles (where certain community users can see some Menu Items, while others cannot). How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If your menu items are the objects, you can use profıles to create different menu ıtems. Profile A can reach object X,Y,Z and see the menu items X,Y,Z,  but Profile B can only reach object X, can see only X menu item.